# slider in tab menu not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

i try working with slider in tab menu. but it not really work nice.

currently i have 3 slider, 1 for main slider and 2 in tab menu.
the error are, for first load page slider in tab menu working well, but when i click another tab, slider stop working and look weird.
here i give attachment with what i do. hope someone can help me to make slider in tab working well.

jsfiddle.net/gihnih/zqbs6yg8/

Comment: Can you upload it so we can test it right away instead of downloading

Comment: @Stringified i already upload. thanks :)